# GPS LAT/Long updating every 5 minutes

Tags: android, gps, geolocation, locationmanager

Hey all I am using the following code in order to get my current LAT and LONG:

```
try{
     locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

     locationListener = new LocationListener() {
         public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                 longitude=location.getLongitude();
                 latitude=location.getLatitude();
                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your Current location is"+"\n"+"Longitude : "+longitude+"\n"+"Latitude : "+latitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
             public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
             public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
             public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
         };

         locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
   }catch(Exception e){
     longitude=0.0;
     latitude=0.0;
}
```

Works just fine but it seems to update every 30 seconds or so. How can i modify the code above to only update every 5 minutes?

I tried:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 10, locationListener);
```

And that seems to update it every 6 minutes? So does 10 = 6 minutes here and therefore 9 would = 5 minutes?

Comment: As mentioned in developer document the 10 = minimum of 10 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29).

The time is milliseconds, so for 5 minutes minimum, you should write (5mn*60s*1000ms = 300000ms):

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 300000, 0, locationListener);
```